# How to find files in a given sector?

Tags: partitioning, sector-size

I'm currently trying to find a file that was *hidden* in sector 2047. My root partition starts at sector 2048.
How would I go about finding that file? Given the only info I have is the sector its in.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just so everyone knows, this question is a forensics question in the cyberpatriot competition state round in the year 2019 (currently ongoing) I don't believe there is an issue with this person asking this question, I just wanted everyone to know.

Answer (score 9):

There's no file hidden in sector 2047. There may be data, but it's not part of the file system.

To recover it:

1. Figure out sector size of disk
2. Read sector with e.g. `dd`

### Figure out sector size

`sudo fdisk -l` will show you sector sizes:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for root: 
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZ7TY256
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
```

Here we have 512B sectors. This is probably the most common; some newer devices will have 4KB sector sizes. This is the reason we need to know the sector size of the device - we have to specify it in the next step, so `dd` knows how many bytes to skip.

### Read out said sector

This `dd` can do for us.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=sector2047 bs=512 skip=2046 count=1
```

- `if=/dev/sda` tells `dd` to read from `/dev/sda`
- `of=sector2047` tells `dd` to write to the file `sector2047`
- `bs=512` tells `dd` to read in 512B increments (block size)
- `skip=2046` tells `dd` to skip first 2046 512B-blocks
- `count=1` tells `dd` to read 1 block of 512B.

Comment: You can also pick up the sector size using either `blockdev --getbsz /dev/sda` or `cat /sys/block/sda/queue/physical_block_size`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the same command vidarlo used, but change the `skip=2046` to `skip=2047` and the `count=1` to `count=3`. This will give a bigger space to search in.

Then do `sudo apt install hexedit`. After that, do `hexedit sector2047` and scroll down until you see your message on the left.

Comment: This works, the poster should accept the answer.

Comment: If `count=3` don't you want `skip=2045`? Also it is best to post full command rather than 2 of the arguments only.

Comment: The question asked for a very specific block, not three blocks, nor what to do with the information - and I explained the syntax rather well, so modifications should be trivial :)