# How to view sectors

Tags: disk

I want to view the contents of a specific sector in a specific partition.  How do I do this?  I do not know the proper command to view an individual sector and its contents.

Comment: Start reading from `man dd`.

Comment: I can't find out how to view the contents of a specific sector though.

Comment: For command line, look at command `od`. For graphic editor, look at `okteta` tool. First copy the relevant sector to a small file and then view it with these tools.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find files in a given sector?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194308/how-to-find-files-in-a-given-sector)